# mounting a SMB share onto Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, mount, fstab

Been trying to mount a NTFS network hard drive on raspbian, I've added the following line within fstab:

```
//192.168.1.X/usb1 /home/pi/Desktop/HDD cifs guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

when I run mount -a it's giving me the following error:

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
```

There's no username or password for the access of this network drive (Kodi inside Raspbian/WindowsOS mounted this drive no problem with no credentials) hence why I though using guest would do the trick.

uid 1000 = pi

Guides I've been following for this task:

http://geeks.noeit.com/mount-an-smb-network-drive-on-raspberry-pi/

http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.x/ForlderOnMac ./FolderOnPi -o user=XXX,password=xxxx,nounix,sec=ntlmssp
```

Edit

From [mount.cifs docs](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html)

> **user** - specifies the username to connect as.
>
> **password** - specifies the CIFS password.
>
> **nounix** - Disable the CIFS Unix Extensions for this mount. This can be useful in order to turn off multiple settings at once. This includes POSIX acls, POSIX locks, POSIX paths, symlink support and retrieving uids/gids/mode from the server. This can also be useful to work around a bug in a server that supports Unix Extensions.
>
> **sec** - Security mode

Comment: Thank you for answering, but would you mind elaborating on your answer in an edit? Why did you setup the command like you did?

Comment: Sure - see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit, unfortunately it's still giving me permission denied, I've tried using user=,password=, aswell as guest... but no luck.

I just don't understand why I can mount it on Kodi but not on Raspbian on the same Pi........

Comment: On your Mac, did you allowing sharing for your folder?

Comment: Yes, my windows box can connect to it without using a user account or password.

Comment: For me to get it to work, I had to export each path component separately.  So if my home directory on the Mac is "/Users/wolf" I need to go into `System Preferences -> Sharing` and use the "+" to add shared folder and SEPARATELY add "/Users" and also "/Users/wolf" - 2 separate entries.